Is there any Example of 8 Points in the Plane that Determine only 4 Ordinary Lines (Gallai Lines)?
I want to find an example of 8 points in the plane that determine only 4 ordinary lines (lines containing exactly 2 points).
I have tried all the shapes I know, but I can’t seem to come up with an example. Your help would be appreciated.

You asked for an example. I gave you two. You said help would be appreciated. I helped. The way to appreciate help on this website is to vote an answer up, if you found it helpful, and to accept it by clicking in the check mark next to it, if it answers your question.

Here's what it says at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem
"the even numbers $n$ greater than four have a matching upper bound
$t_{2}(n)\leq n/2$ [that is, a bound on the number of ordinary lines given $n$ points in the plane]. The construction, due to Károly Böröczky, that achieves this bound consists of the vertices of a regular
$m$-gon in the real projective plane and another
$m$ points (thus,
$n=2m$) on the line at infinity corresponding to each of the directions determined by pairs of vertices. Although there are
$m(m-1)/2$ pairs of these points, they determine only
$m$ distinct directions. This arrangement has only
$m$ ordinary lines, the lines that connect a vertex
$v$ with the point at infinity collinear with the two neighbors of
$v$. As with any finite configuration in the real projective plane, this construction can be perturbed so that all points are finite, without changing the number of ordinary lines."
A reference is Crowe, D. W.; McKee, T. A. (1968), "Sylvester's problem on collinear points", Mathematics Magazine, 41 (1): 30–34, doi:10.2307/2687957, JSTOR 2687957, MR 0235452
Here's an example. Take the eight points $A=(0,6)$; $B=(8,6)$; $C=(12,6)$; $D=(24,6)$; $E=(3,3)$; $F=(4,2)$; $G=(-6,0)$; $H=(-12,-6)$. Then, the lines are $ABCD$; $AGH$; $AEF$; $BEH$; $CEG$; $CFH$; $DFG$; and the four ordinary lines $BF$; $BG$; $DE$; $DH$.
Here's a simpler example, from Kelly, L. M., and W. O. J. Moser, On the number of ordinary lines determined by $n$ points, Canadian Journal of Mathematics 10 (1958): 210–19. https://doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1958-024-6. Take a triangle $ABC$. Let $D$ be the centroid (intersection of the three medians). Let $E,F,G$, respectively, be the midpoint of $BC,AC,AB$, respectively. Let $H$ be the intersection of $FG$ and $AE$. Then the only ordinary lines are $BH$, $CH$, $EF$, and $EG$.

I searched the reference on Google Scholar and got only the first page. I was able to follow the construction described in section 3: I came up with a 4-gon standing on one of its vertices. Then, I inscribed a 4-gon in it so that this inscribed 4-gon sits on its edge, with each of its vertices on the edge of the outer 4-gon.

So, you got it to work?

the edges of the interior 4-gon should be exactly what we are looking for. Or, what do you think?

It's hard for me to visualize your description. Can you write down coordinates of the eight points?

Any thoughts on my examples, Mr Prof?
